# how can I connect to fornite api in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using a package to connect my backend in Laravel to fornite, I am using this package: https://github.com/Tustin/fortnite-php the problem is that just when I try to use the test it throws me this error:

```
message": "cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations:\n  CAfile: C:\\PHP\\cacert.pem\n  CApath: none (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html),
```

Basically I just have a simple axios call on created in my componen, which goes to a route defines in my web.php:

```
Route::get('/kid/fornite', 'ProfileController@fortnite')->name('fortnite');
```

and this is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Services\ProfileService;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateProfileRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

 require_once '../../../vendor/autoload.php';

use Fortnite\Auth;
use Fortnite\Account;
use Fortnite\Mode;
use Fortnite\Language;
use Fortnite\Platform;


    public function fortnite(){
        // Authenticate
        $auth = Auth::login('email@email.com','somepassword');
        dd($auth);
        // Output each stat for all applicable platforms
        var_dump($auth->profile->stats);

        // Grab someone's stats
        $sandy = $auth->profile->stats->lookup('sandalzrevenge');
        echo 'Sandy Ravage has won ' . $sandy->pc->solo->wins . ' solo games and ' . $sandy->pc->squad->wins . ' squad games!';
    }
```

Comment: You might want to hide your login information the next time you post on SO. If this is your real credentials I would change them asap

Comment: I mean your fortnite credentials, not just here

Comment: yes I have done it. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to curl certification:

Note: If using Wamp server here is the proper implementation.

**Step1:** Download: `caert.pem`

**Step2:** Paste it in `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\extras\ssl`

**Step3:** Configure this in `php.ini`(In the right bottom click wamp icon got to php.ini) `curl.cainfo = "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"`

**Step4:** Configure this in php.ini Manaully(`C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\php.ini) curl.cainfo = "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"`

**Step5:** restart wamp

**IF you are not using WAMP or XAMPP**

**Step1:** Download that file from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)
**Ste2:** Then add it to your php extras folder
 - put in my extras folder in php 7.2

**Step3:** Then in your `php.ini` file  add the path of your file in `curl.cainfo`

```
curl.cainfo = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.2\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

- then save php.ini
- then restart my iis or just website

Reference:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/curl-error-77-error-setting-certificate-verify-locations-cafile-cwamp64binphpphp719extrassslcacertpem-capath-none

Comment: thanks for replying! how/where do I download the caert.pem? this might seems obvious what I have been using Laravel for a month roughly

Comment: aparently I am nos using wamp

Comment: it looks like I am not xD

Comment: neither I am working on local at the moment it is not deplyed yet